# (ServiceStack) Location of business logic in a message based architecture

Tags: security, servicestack

What is the best practice for placing business logic in message based design?

Im using servicestack for building my api.

[The wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#user-content-the-authenticate-attribute) shows the example of placing the `RequiredRole` Attribute on the message instead of the service handling it.

In a sense this `[RequiredRole]`/`[Authenticate]` is business logic/security attached to the message.

## Concrete example

Say for example i would add `DeleteAddress` message:

```
public class DeleteAddress : IReturn<bool>
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

But for this to be properly secure i want to check either Admin Role, permission to ManageAllAddresses or that the AddressId is linked to this user (maybe in session, maybe through a db call).

How would i best go about this?

## Proposition

Is the following code the good practice and if so how would i implement it?

```
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
[RequiredPermission("ManageAllAddresses ")]
[RequiredAddressLinkedToAccount]
public class DeleteAddress : IReturn<bool>
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thx for the pointer on the stale docs on the wiki, we'll update them to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's recommendation is to keep your ServiceModel free of dependencies so we'd recommend to annotate your Service implementation classes instead which you can annotate either on the Service class to apply to all Operations or on the individual methods to apply just to that operation, e.g:

```
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
public class AddressServices : Service
{
    [RequiredPermission("ManageAllAddresses ")]
    [RequiredAddressLinkedToAccount]
    public object Any(DeleteAddress request)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Please note ServiceStack requires your Services to return **reference** types, which is typically a Response DTO but can also be a `string`, e.g:

```
public class DeleteAddress : IReturn<string>
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To finish of this question. I could make a request filter and add it on the service.

Either inherit from AuthenticateAttribute or Directly from RequestFilterAttribute.

```
public class RequiredAddressLinkedToAccount : AuthenticateAttribute
{
    public RequiredRoleAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo)
    {
        this.ApplyTo = applyTo;
        this.Priority = (int)RequestFilterPriority.RequiredRole;
    }



    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var dto = requestDto as ILinkedToAccount;
        var session = req.GetSession();
        if(dto.AccountId == session.Id)
            return; //we dont want anything to be blocked if the account Id is there.

        //Implement like RequireRoleAttribute
        if (DoHtmlRedirectIfConfigured(req, res)) 
            return;

        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        res.StatusDescription = "Address does not belong to you";
        res.EndRequest();

    }
}
```